# ::selection from CSS affects layout

Tags: css

UPDATED:

I have found out this : margin: 0 auto; in the body {} block of the style sheet makes the header move. If I remove it, the banner header picture moves to the right. So that piece of line is the culprit. Does anybody know why?

As I have progressed (somewhat in the mystery) the question goes the other way.

I have this header file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo base_url() ?>css/main_style.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo base_url() ?>css/webform.css" />

    </head>
    <div id="header" class = "header"><h1 class="header">Real Estate Worldwide</h1> </div>

<body>
```

Which connects to this View file (I am on MVC)

The code in the view has nothing to do with the issue, I asked so we'll skip it.

Then I have this Style sheet.

```
<style type = "text/css">
::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::-moz-selection {background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }





body {



        background:url('../assets/uploads/miweb/gradient2.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-x;

        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
        width:600px;
        height:500px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
#header {

    float:center;
    background: url("../jq185/css/start/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_75_2191c0_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #2191C0;
    font-family: 'trebuchet ms',geneva,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1050px;
    h2 {color:#ffffff;}


}
    .header {

    color:#ffffff;
    }
```

ISSUE:

If I remove the 3 selection ::selection lines from the style sheet, the gradient effect, from the background body disappears.

If I leave it there, then the gradient effect works but then the #header jpg file that you see down the style sheet changes its position from the centered marging: 0 auto; to the right.

You have the full code there. I am puzzled as hell, because I cannot understand why something like ::selection would have a radical effect on the code snippet that refers to body {} where the call to the gradient picture is and also affects the font style within that body {}

II UPDATE

Here is the Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home_c extends CI_Controller {



    function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('home_model');


    }


    public function index ()

    {

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('home');

    }




    public function load()


    {   $this->load->view('header');
        $data['paises'] = $this->home_model->devolverPaises();
        $data['ofertas'] = $this->home_model->devolverOfertas();
```

Comment: Just a really quick note: there's no such thing as `float:center`.

Comment: Also ... where's your `<body>` tag in your header file?
I wouldn't be surprised if the strange effects you're seeing are tied to not having proper markup, if that's not just a typo in the code you typed into your question.

Comment: hmm ok i will remove it but, in the latest update above I indicate the line that is giving me trouble. Do you know why ?

Comment: I copied and pasted so no typo in here, hmmm, so..then? i put that body tag... one second

Comment: Well, again, you don't have a `<body>` tag in the code you provided. Your style is hooked to the body, and I'm not certain what other browser quirks you'll run into without proper markup, there, but I'd make sure you have valid markup before you try debugging the CSS further.

Comment: I added the <body> tag in the header.. but not much of a change. I added it right after all of the other code

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS? And did you remember to close your `<body>` in whatever file you're using to generate the footer of your pages?

Comment: What do you mean by "right after all of the other code"? The structure of an HTML page needs to go: `<!declaration >` then `<html>` then (optionally)`<head>... </head>` then `<body> <!-- all your other code --> </body>` -> `</html>` to properly validate.

Comment: You have a body spec in your CSS, but you didn't have a `<body>` tag for it to affect. The browsers will fill in the gaps, in some cases, but the farther you deviate from standards, the less likely you are to see the same result from browser to browser, as IE may interpret bad markup differently from Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: And you put your `<body>`, above, after your `<div id="header">` so I thought it'd be a good idea to clarify how the structure must appear.

Comment: appreciate it. I positioned the header by using the margin 0 270px; but...since the header is on its own, i dont think this is a solution even though I see it well, because I am afraid it will be like the position:absolute. no good if if you are on the top container, it will look differently positioned depending on the size of the screen monitor..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if the strange effects you're seeing are tied to not having proper markup.

EDITED: As I made comments, I realized the may not have been clear enough for OP.

Your HTML structure needs to be valid, to start with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- title, meta, styles, etc go here -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- all your other content goes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure that when your page renders in the browser, when you look at View Source, you see those container elements in their proper places, nested as such. Better yet, run your page through a validation service. (http://validator.w3.org/ for example)

You have invalid CSS:

```
#header {
    float:center; /* no such attribute... only left, right, none, or inherit */
    h2 {color:#ffffff;} /* you can't nest tags inside other specs, except with the use of pre-processors like SASS or LESS */
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted so no typo in here, hmmm, so..then? i put that body tag... one second

Comment: I added the <body> tag in the header.. but not much of a change. I added it right after all of the other code

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS? And did you remember to close your `<body>` in whatever file you're using to generate the footer of your pages?

Comment: What do you mean by "right after all of the other code"? The structure of an HTML page needs to go: `<!declaration >` then `<html>` then (optionally)`<head>... </head>` then `<body> <!-- all your other code --> </body>` -> `</html>` to properly validate.